# Special Killing Vector Fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Consider $(M^{n},g)$ to be a Riemannian manifold and suppose that $X$ is a smooth non-trivial Killing vector field on $M$.  Away from the zeros of $X$ we have a natural distribution $D$ of $(n-1)$-planes defined so that $D_p$ is orthogonal to $X_p$. If the distribution $D$ is (completely) integrable then it is straightforward to verify that the one form $\omega$ defined by
$$\omega(\cdot )=\frac{1}{g(X,X)} g(X, \cdot).$$
is closed (away from $\lbrace X=0\rbrace$).  Moreover, the converse also holds.

Examples in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the euclidean metric include the the translations along the $x_i$-axis, $T_i$ and  rotations around the $x_i$-axis, $R_i$.  The Killing fields $T_i+R_i$ are non-examples.

My question is whether this concept already has a name and where it might appear in the literature.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but such Killing vectors are *twist-free*; although this condition seems stronger.  Recall that a Killing vector $X$ is twist-free if $X^\flat \wedge dX^\flat = 0$, where $X^\flat = g(X,\cdot)$ in your notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now think that my comment might indeed be the complete answer in the case when $X$ has no zeroes.
Guiseppe's answer has been a sort of Socratic catalyst.

Indeed, in that case the distribution $D$ defined by $\omega$ and $X^\flat$ agree.  So $D$ is integrable if and only if the ideal generated by either $\omega$ or $X^\flat$ is differentiably closed, hence $dX^\flat = \alpha \wedge X^\flat$ for some one-form $\alpha$.  In turn this is equivalent to $X^\flat \wedge dX^\flat = 0$, which is precisely the condition that $X$ be *twist-free*.

Comment: Great!

I figured there was a more convenient way to think about things.

Answer (score 2):

Mine is not an answer but a question. I'll delete it if it is improper.

Why, as the questioner says,  if $X$ were Killing and $D$ integrable then $\frac{1}{X^\flat(X)}.X^\flat$ should be closed on $M$? Could someone explain me the reason for this?

Here follows what I have understood:

Given a smooth non-singular vector field $X$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, we get the smooth distribution $D$ on $M$ globally generated by the smooth non-vanishing 1-form $X^\flat=g(X,\cdot)$.
By Frobenius' Theorem, $D$ is integrable iff ${X^\flat}\wedge{d{X^\flat}}=0$ on $M$.
This integrability condition is at the same time necessary and sufficient for the local existence of integrating factors for $X^\flat$: i.e. for any point $p$ of $M$, there exists a function $f$ such that $f.X^\flat$ is closed in a neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: As it ended up answering the question your approach makes the most sense.  The way I thought about things was:

Fix a point $p$ so that $X(p)\neq 0$ Let $U$ be a small neighborhood of $p$ so that in $p$ there is a smooth surface $\Sigma$ through $p$ and normal to $X$.  Let $\phi_s$ be the family of isometries generated by $X$ clearly for $U$ small enough $\phi_s(\Sigma)$ foliate $U$ and all the leaves are orthogonal to $X$.  This allows one to think of $s$ as a function  on $U$. One has $ds=\frac{X}{|X|^2}$.